# How to exec MariaDB stored procedure from Visual Foxpro?

Tags: mariadb, foxpro

I have a function/stored procedure in Maria DB:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test1`(var1 varchar(100))
BEGIN
  select * from ttype where kode=var1;
END
```

I need to get a cursor from that stored procedure, how to get a cursor in vfp application, database in MariaDb/MySQL stored procedure?

I try with this in my Visual Foxpro:

```
Sqlexec(kon,"call test1 ('ABC')","test")     --> not running
```

But when I use common select like this :

```
sqlexec(kon,"select * from ttype where kode='ABC'","test")
```

it's running well.

Comment: From a `Vfp` point of view, normally the second parameter of `SqlExec` would be exactly the same command string that would work in your MariaDB "Database Workbench", given that the connection/user privileges are sufficient

Comment: Please edit your question and include details on what AERROR() returns in the array after the SQLEXEC() command that is not working.

Comment: Can you show me hot to use aerror() in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Can you show me how to use aerror() in my case?"*

You would use the AError() function always when any ODBC Remote action would fail, i.e. any of Vfp's `SQL*()` functions, like `SqlStringConnect()` for example or your proposed

```
sqlexec(kon,"select * from ttype where kode='ABC'","test") --it's running well
```

&& Actually you cannot know whether *"it's running well"* unless you are evaluating its return value like this:

```
Local lnResult, laSqlErrors[1], lcErrorMessage
lnResult = SqlExec(kon,"select * from ttype where kode='ABC'","test")
If m.lnResult = –1 && as documented in the F1 Help
        AERROR(laSqlErrors)
        lcErrorMessage = ;
            TRANSFORM(laSqlErrors[1]) + ", " + ;
            TRANSFORM(laSqlErrors[2])
        && now write a log and/or inform the user
ENDIF
&& to be continued
```

Comment: THank's for the answer

sqlexec(kon,"select * from ttype where kode='ABC'","test") --it's running well
I can browse the result...
Sqlexec(kon,"call test1 ('ABC')","test") --> I can't browse the result..
It's already fixed when I reinstall my odbc driver...
Visual foxpro is application 32 bit.. when I user odbc driver 32 bit..IT's running well..Thank's a lot...